# Correlation among multiple categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, correlation, categorical-data

[image: my original dataset]

I have a data set made of 22 **categorical variables** (non-ordered). I would like to visualize their correlation in a nice **heatmap**. Since the Pandas built-in function

```
DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
```

only implement correlation coefficients for numerical variables (Pearson, Kendall, Spearman), I have to aggregate it myself to perform a chi-square or something like it and I am not quite sure which function use to do it in **one elegant step** (rather than iterating through all the cat1*cat2 pairs). To be clear, this is what I would like to end up with (a **dataframe**):

```
         cat1  cat2  cat3  
  cat1|  coef  coef  coef  
  cat2|  coef  coef  coef
  cat3|  coef  coef  coef
```

Any ideas with **pd.pivot_table** or something in the same vein?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can using [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

```
df.apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0]).corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
Out[32]: 
     a    c    d
a  1.0  1.0  1.0
c  1.0  1.0  1.0
d  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'c':['a','b','c'],'d':['a','b','c']})
```

Update

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare

df=df.apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0])+1

pd.DataFrame([chisquare(df[x].values,f_exp=df.values.T,axis=1)[0] for x in df])

Out[123]: 
     0    1    2    3
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','d','c'],'c':['a','b','c'],'d':['a','b','c'],'e':['a','b','c']})
```

Comment: sounds like a good plan but, from what I understood, I can't use pearson on categorical data. Would it be possible to modify this code to end up with chi-squared?

Comment: @DavidZarebski https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html

Comment: I saw it but I end up with a (8124, 22) matrix instead of the (22,22) I am looking for. (I have 8124 observation). If you see what I mean

Comment: @DavidZarebski you can check this one : -) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96761/chi-square-independence-test-for-two-pandas-df-columns

Comment: @DavidZarebski isn't the Pearson test's full name the _Pearson's chi-squared test_ ? I think you might be overly complicating things by avoiding it.

Comment: @robertotomás There is something called the Pearson's chi-squared test (which leads to some confusions sometimes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)) and yes, it is intended to measure the correlation between categorical variables (like a regular Chi2). However, it seems to me that it differs from the so called Pearson correlation (resp. Kendall, Spearman)  (see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)) intended to apply to numerical variables. Calling the .corr(method='pearson') method in pandas involves the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the only solution I found is to iterate trough all the factor*factor pairs.

```
factors_paired = [(i,j) for i in df.columns.values for j in df.columns.values] 

chi2, p_values =[], []

for f in factors_paired:
    if f[0] != f[1]:
        chitest = chi2_contingency(pd.crosstab(df[f[0]], df[f[1]]))   
        chi2.append(chitest[0])
        p_values.append(chitest[1])
    else:      # for same factor pair
        chi2.append(0)
        p_values.append(0)

chi2 = np.array(chi2).reshape((23,23)) # shape it as a matrix
chi2 = pd.DataFrame(chi2, index=df.columns.values, columns=df.columns.values) # then a df for convenience
```

Comment: zar3bski Where is Chitest defined here?

Comment: [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) I would say (it's been a while). I must have included something like `from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency` in the beginning of the script (which I do not have anymore)

Comment: why do you use chitest

Comment: why did you use 23, 23 to reshape the array, is it because OP has mentioned he has 22 categorical columns?

Answer (score 3):

Using association-metrics python package to calculate Cramér's coefficient matrix from a pandas.DataFrame object it's quite simple; let me show you:

First install association_metrics using:

```
pip install association-metrics
```

Then, you can use the following pseudocode

```
# Import association_metrics  
import association_metrics as am
# Convert you str columns to Category columns
df = df.apply(
        lambda x: x.astype("category") if x.dtype == "O" else x)

# Initialize a CamresV object using you pandas.DataFrame
cramersv = am.CramersV(df) 
# will return a pairwise matrix filled with Cramer's V, where columns and index are 
# the categorical variables of the passed pandas.DataFrame
cramersv.fit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` to find statistic based on Chi Squared Test. And then you calculate Cramers V formula as in the `cramers_V` function.

This solution has only one `for` loop to iterate through rows and it uses `apply` to iterate through columns so it might be somewhat efficient.

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a1','a2','a1','a1','a1'],
                 'B':['b1','b2','b2','b2','b2'],
                 'C':['c1','c2','c1','c1','c1'],
                 'D':['d1','d2','d1','d2','d1']})

def cramers_V(var1, var2):
    crosstab = np.array(pd.crosstab(var1, var2))
    stats = chi2_contingency(crosstab)[0]
    cram_V = stats / (np.sum(crosstab) * (min(crosstab.shape) - 1))
    return cram_V

def cramers_col(column_name):
    col = pd.Series(np.empty(df.columns.shape), index=df.columns, name=column_name)
    for row in df:
        cram = cramers_V(df[column_name], df[row])
        col[row] = round(cram, 2)
    return col

df.apply(lambda column: cramers_col(column.name))
```

The result for each pair of features will range from 0 to 1, the stronger correlation - the higher value.

Output:

```
    A       B       C       D
A   0.14    0.00    0.14    0.01
B   0.00    0.14    0.00    0.00
C   0.14    0.00    0.14    0.01
D   0.01    0.00    0.01    0.34
```

As expected, A-C correlation is the most significant.

Also, if Chi squared test is calculated by hand for this example (using degrees of freedom and all), A-C correlation is the strongest there as well.